# Swift TableViewCell xib doesn't have constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard, xib

I have two `TableView`s, when I designed the original I designed it using the prototype cell in the storyboard, to make it reusable I tried to pull it out into a `.xib` and load that instead. When it is loaded from `cellID.xib` however it loses all the constraints at runtime, and everything is layered on top of each other.

### TableViewController

```
let cellIdentifier = "cellID"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: cellIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
}
```

### Prototype cell in Storyboard (Used to work)

[image: prototype cell]

### Cell when copy pasted to XIB

[image: xib cell]

### Constraints

[image: contraints on cell]

### XIB View Hierarchy

[image: xib view hierarchy]

Comment: @KKRocks Nope, I already tried that. The constraints work fine when they are in the prototype cell, it's only when I copy and pasted into a nib that it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @KKRocks You're not paying attention. UITableViewAutomaticDimension works just fine.

Comment: try to add this lines before return cell :  cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

Comment: @KKRocks Didn't fix it, I now get this warning `Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.`

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot of the view hierarchy in the nib (just the left panel is enough)?

Comment: @xoudini Added.

Comment: @Aaronepower, do you have a github link to this project that you could post?

Comment: @Aaronepower, I tested your project based on the info you've given. I even tried copy/pasting a cell from a storyboard prototype to a xib. I did not have any constraints issues. The screenshots that you posted seem this you have a demo project going. I suggest you post a github link so that we can further investigate what is going on. I'll post an answer soon with my findings.

Comment: @Aaronepower take a look at my answer and sample project. let me know if you have any questions. thanks

Comment: @Aaronepower did solved you problem ?

Comment: @Aaronepower : i hope you have got the solution from my answer below , if not than reply back in the comment ....  Solution enable `Use Auto Layout` from `File Inspector`

Comment: Will you send me your demo ? Just for What you have done in your project? I can check it and return back to you with answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Problem

In your question title, you asked how to solve an issue where "Swift TableViewCell xib doesn't have constraints." Additionally in the bounty, you specify that the answer should be:

> An adequate answer showing why constraints are lost when moved to a
>   xib, when they exist in the xib, and how to address this problem.

From my understanding, your question has two parts:

1. Issue where a custom TableViewCell xib does not have constraints
2. Why constraints are lost when copy/pasted from Storyboard prototype to a xib

For issue #1, I used almost all of the same constraints as you had displayed in your screenshot in a custom cell xib and it worked. I will explain in more detail below.

For issue #2, I found that constraints are not lost. You may need to share your project so that others can replicate the issue you are having. I copy/pasted a Storyboard prototype cell with similar constraints over to a xib and I did not have any issues with constraints. So I can confirm that the copy/paste feature does work.

### Solution Demo

I created the following demo to test your issue. Refer to the screenshot below. The tableView contains six cells. The 1st and 2nd are the same and have reuse identifier `MyCell`. The 3rd and 4th are the same and have reuse identifier `MyCopyPasteCell`. The 5th and 6th are the same and have reuse identifier `MyPrototypeCell`.

`MyCell` exists in a xib and uses nearly all the same constraints that you showed in your screenshot. As you can see, there are no constraints issues. `MyCopyPasteCell` uses similar constraints and was copy/pasted from a Storyboard prototype over to a xib. `MyPrototypeCell` is the original prototype that was copied. These last four cells look exactly the same even though the prototype was copied over to the xib. The constraints carried over from prototype to xib without an issue.

[image]

### Constraints

In the code below, I list all the constraints that you showed in your screenshot for your **ContentView**. (Note that I also implemented the `height=20`, `aspect=1:1`, and `height=75` constraints, although they are not listed below.) Two constraints are commented out since I did not use them. I also added one more constraint to replace another unused one.

```
// bottomMargin = Profile Image View.bottom + 188.5
bottomMargin = Profile Image.bottom + 17
Profile Image View.top = Username Label.top
Profile Image View.leading = leadingMargin + 2
Profile Image View.top = topMargin + 20
Username Label.leading = Content Text View.leading    
// Username Label.top = topMargin + 20        
Username Label.trailing = Content Text View.trailing
Username Label.leading = Profile Image View.trailing + 15
trailingMargin = Username Label.trailing + 10
Content Text View.top = Username Label.bottom + 5
Content Text View.leading = leadingMargin + 92
bottomMargin = Content Text View.bottom + 20
```

The first commented constraint `// bottomMargin = Profile Image View.bottom + 188.5` did not make sense as it would separate the bottom of the image from the bottom of the cell by 188.5. This also did not match your **Prototype cell in Storyboard (Used to work)** screenshot at all. I replaced it with `bottomMargin = Profile Image.bottom + 17`, which just replaces the 188.5 with 17.

The second commented constraint `// Username Label.top = topMargin + 20` (which separates username and topMargin by 20) can technically work. However, its functionality is redundant to `Profile Image.top = topMargin + 20` (which separates Profile Image and topMargin by 20) and `Profile Image View.top = Username Label.top` (which sets the Profile Image and Username to the same top separation i.e. by 20).

### MyTableViewController

The following is my view controller. Basically I create three sections with two cells/rows per section. `MyCell` and `MyCopyPasteTableViewCell` are from a xib and are registered in the `viewDidLoad()`. `MyPrototypeCell` is from the Storyboard and is not registered in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
//  MyTableViewController.swift
import UIKit    
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let myCell = "MyCell"
    let myCopyPasteCell = "MyCopyPasteTableViewCell"
    let myPrototypeCell = "MyPrototypeCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: myCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: myCell)
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: myCopyPasteCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: myCopyPasteCell)
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myCell, for: indexPath)
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myCopyPasteCell, for: indexPath)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: myPrototypeCell, for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

### Github link

https://github.com/starkindustries/TableViewCellConstraintsTest

Answer (score 2):

**Problem and Solution**

You may have disabled the `Autolayout` for your XIB to turn it `ON` go to `File Inspector` from Top Right Menu

[image]

**You Can Follow the Simple Steps to Create Cell from Xib**

**1.** Create `UITableCell` with `.xib` ( ✅  also create Xib file)
[image]

**2.** Give the cell identifier

[image]

**3.** Layout **Constraints**

`ImageView` give contarints from `Top` , `Left` and `Bottom`
       height constant and Aspect ratio [i have set Border to show the frame]

`UIlable` for the `title lable` give constraints from three sides
       from `Top` , `Left` and `Right` `NumberOflines=0`   (  Don't give height constant - 
  ⚠️ if gives warning go ahead and update the constraints)

`UIlable` for the `Descriptions lable` give constraints from all four sides  also `NumberOflines=0`
        (⚠️  This will give you an error go to suggestion and change the priority of `UIlable` constraints)

see the screenshot below [image]

*changing priority* [image]
 than again update contraints

**4.** Code in `UIViewController`

```
 @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var cellIdentifier="cell"
    var cellXibName = "MyTableCell"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: cellXibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 320


    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView1: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView1: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell :MyTableCell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyTableCell


            return cell
    }
```

And Finally the Output is perfect as you want

**OUTPUT**[image]

I hope this will work for you...... please let me know if this worked for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

I was achive solution to your problem. hope it might be help to you

I use uiview to clips all  cell elements.[image]

And Cell Design 
[image]

Code :

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!



 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TestCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TestCell")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCell

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }

}
```

Result :
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the cell height is the problem, right? Because of that the constraints can't do their work correctly.

You need this override func when you work with `XIB files`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 300
}
```

However your constraints must be wrong or let us say they are not perfect. I know they are working with the prototype cells in storyboard but that don't make them 100% perfect working right?
Your `UIImageView` has no `height` and `width`. You should try to set that with some constraints. (or you set the `width` and use the `Aspect Ratio` constraint)

Comment: How else would you re use cells across view controllers? setting an explicit height is not an answer as I need automatic height.

Comment: I can understand that but xibs require it. Try it. It should work and if not there are more issues in your code and implementation of the xib files than only that.