# Text in table view cell not wrapping to second line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a cell which may have to display a long text. In this case it should wrap to a second line.

I have **Lines** set to **2** and **Line Break** set to **Word Wrap** in the attributes Inspector. The Interface Builder preview confirm that and behaves as expected/desired.

[image]

When building and running however the text is limited to one line and truncuates at the tail:
[image]

Other changes in the attribute inspector seem to have no effect aswell (text alignment for example)!

Comment: In your UITableViewDelegate, what are you returning as heightForRow ?

Comment: In the class that powers the shown table view I have not functions mentioning _heightForRow_

Comment: Check this answer maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/30300870/1422333

Comment: set number of line to zero , and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in height

Comment: see this is answered here , add contraints and follow the steps   here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43656451/4466607

Comment: What I was missing was width constraints on the label.

Answer (score 8):

**If anyone is still having the problem..**
Here's the solution for swift 4 Xcode 9 iOS 11

> inside the cellForRowAt tableview function you just have to add a single line of code

```
cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**

Add Two Methods in tableview.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
                return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
                return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

Comment: But why is it neccessary to change the heigth of the row, when I only want to change the line breaking. Also, other changes in the attribute Inspector to  the cell don't seem to have any effect either.

Comment: You are use autolayout or size class?

Answer (score 3):

For getting the lines without the dots, Do the following -

1. Take the UILabel inside the cell, go to the attribute inspector.
2. In the attribute inspector find lines and change it to 0.
3. Then, change the line break to WordWrap

I think this will work.

Comment: As described in my question, that is precisely what I already did.

Comment: In the question you described it as line is set to 2.

Comment: This is the correct solution. I tried all the other suggestions to do it in code but this is what worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement automatic cell sizing depending on the label's text size

1. In your cell, add constraints for Top and Bottom of UILabel, but not for cell height or label height
2. In your table view set
   `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

This will make the cells resize according to label's contents

Comment: Where do you add this declaration? In a specific method? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple lines in label so in attributes inspector set **lines to 0** 
and implement

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Where do you add this declaration? In a specific method? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints might not have set properly for the UILabel. So, the UILabel will keep on expanding as the text increases.

- **Set the UILabel constraints with autolayout constraints** or give a static width (or left and right properties).
- Now in label attributes inspector **set lines to 0**